# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wpdb::prepare():update

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am getting the following error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function wpdb::prepare(), 1 passed in
>   /homepages/39/d740877019/htdocs/test/wp-content/themes/eduma/formulaire_get.php
>   on line 108 and exactly 2 expected in
>   /homepages/39/d740877019/htdocs/test/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1222 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /homepages/39/d740877019/htdocs/test/wp-content/themes/eduma/formulaire_get.php(108):
>   wpdb->prepare('UPDATE wp_pmpro...') #1
>   /homepages/39/d740877019/htdocs/test/wp-includes/template.php(688):
>   require_once('/homepages/39/d...') #2
>   /homepages/39/d740877019/htdocs/test/wp-content/themes/eduma/wrapper.php(14):
>   load_template('/homepages/39/d...') #3
>   /homepages/39/d740877019/htdocs/test/wp-includes/template-loader.php(74):
>   include('/homepages/39/d...') #4
>   /homepages/39/d740877019/htdocs/test/wp-blog-header.php(19):
>   require_once('/homepages/39/d...') #5
>   /homepages/39/d740877019/htdocs/test/index.php(17):
>   require('/homepages/39/d...') #6 {main} thrown in
>   /homepages/39/d740877019/htdocs/test/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line
>   1222

The line in question is the second one below :

```
$current_price = (($ecoles * $classes)/10)*28 ; 
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_pmpro_membership_levels SET initial_payment='".$current_price."' WHERE name = mairie"));
```

Comment: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/

Comment: this reponse is about select or update ?

Comment: Prepare expects you to be passing in 2 or more arguments with sprintf-style placeholders. ([src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)). If you want to do it this way, use `query` instead.

Comment: If you want to insert `$current_price` into your query directly instead of using a placeholder as expected by `prepare()`, you should also `mysql_real_escape_string()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolve my probleme :

```
$current_price = (($ecoles * $classes)/10)*28 ; 
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_pmpro_membership_levels 
                SET initial_payment='%s' 
                WHERE name = %s",$current_price,'mairie'));
```